# How do I iterate through two arrays individually

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, zip, enumerator

My own little project is to merge two logs based on timestamps, both logs have the same timestamp. Some rows do not have timestamps and should be printed with the row with timestamp.

so if I have logs like this:

```
2015-06-25 09:20:25,654 file1 text2
2015-06-25 09:20:23,654 file1 text1
test text1 belongs to the row above
2015-06-25 09:20:27,654 file1 text3
```

And the other file is the same way but with different time stamps.
As I'm new to Ruby I found that this project might be a good way to start.

So far I've found enough help that I should use Enumerators and I guess a

```
loop do
  code
end
```

But how do I decide when I want to  iterate file1 without file2 will iterate too?
And how do I find out when one iterator is at the end of a file so I can print the rest of the other file?

Should I read the files to each array first or just work two streams to each file and one stream to the output file?

summary: I want to iterate through two files until one file reached the end, then print the last rows in the other file and having control over when the iteration should happen in both files.

Thank you for your time and input!

**Edit: **

But I want to merge them together with timestamps. Like:
2015-06-25 09:20:24,123 file1 text1

2015-06-25 09:20:23,123 file2 text1
2015-06-25 09:20:26,123 file2 text2

Output:
2015-06-25 09:20:23,123 file2 text1
2015-06-25 09:20:24,123 file1 text1
2015-06-25 09:20:26,123 file2 text2

Basicly if I have two arrays I iterate over with iterator x and y.
If x > y then put y in the output file and do like y++ then keep checking them against eachother until the end of a file. If x is eof, just add the rest of y to the output file.

Comment: You can check if you are at the end of your input file stream using [eof?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-eof-3F). As far as knowing when you want to read from file 1 or 2, that comes down to your requirements. I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean when you say "then print the last rows in the other file". If you could clarify that I could provide example code in an answer.

Comment: So the logs are using the same syntax. date time info text a normal Log4j output and sometimes there is a stacktrace with and there is no date time at the beginning of the line.
So when I iterate through two files and merging them to a big single output file I want to take all the data thats left in file2 and just push it all to the output file if file1 reaches it's destination or file2 for that matter because I know the timestamp is higher because its the eof in file1.

I hope that clears up something.

Comment: How big are the files potentially? That is the biggest problem I see with this, as they will need to both fit in memory.

Comment: They can be up to a GB or 1.5GB. But mostly around 800~ish. I'm trying to get a linear solution and not an exponetial one. But my problem right now is the syntax in Ruby and how I can iterate through it. I know about zip and then maybe some type of sort but that might take very long in big logs?
It might be the wrong language to use here but I really like the Ruby syntax so I want to learn.

Comment: I will continue to give this some thought and see what I come up with. Using something like zip will require both of the lists to be in memory all at once, which is something that probably needs to be avoided with a possible 3GB between the two lists.

Comment: Okay, give what I came up with a shot. I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is what I ended up coming up with. I believe that it should work for you, with the following implementation:

- If the current line from each file starts with a parseable date, then the oldest wins (change the `<` on line 49 to `>` to swap that).
- When a line is written to the output, the file that line was read from is cycled and the next line is grabbed. The line from the other file stays intact until that line has its turn to be written.
- If a line does not start with a parseable date, that line wins and is written. As stated above, that file is cycled and the next line is pulled in, repeating until there is a parseable date again or it hits the end of the file.
- If one of the files reaches its end, the other file will be streamed to the output until it also reaches its output.

Please note that you will need to change `'file1'`, `'file2'`, and `'output'` to file paths, relative or absolute. You can use `ARGV` or [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) to use command line arguments to pass this data into the program.

Input files:

```
# file1

2014-06-21 07:20:25,654 file1 text2
2015-01-13 14:24:23,654 file1 text1
test text1 belongs to the row above
2015-06-21 08:57:27,654 file1 text3
```

---

```
# file2

2013-01-05 19:27:25,654 file1 text2
2015-04-01 10:13:23,654 file1 text1
test text5 belongs to the row above
2015-06-23 09:49:27,654 file1 text3
```

---

```
# output

2013-01-05 19:27:25,654 file1 text2
2014-06-21 07:20:25,654 file1 text2
2015-01-13 14:24:23,654 file1 text1
test text1 belongs to the row above
2015-04-01 10:13:23,654 file1 text1
test text5 belongs to the row above
2015-06-21 08:57:27,654 file1 text3
2015-06-23 09:49:27,654 file1 text3
```

---

```
# compile_files.rb

require 'date'

# Attempt to read a line from the supplied file.
# If this fails, we are at the end of the file and return nil.
def read_line_from_file(file)
  file.readline
rescue EOFError
  nil
end

# Parse the date which is at the beginning of the supplied text.
# If this fails, it doesn't start with a date so we return nil.
def parse_date(text)
  DateTime.parse(text)
rescue ArgumentError
  nil
end

begin
  # Open the files to sort
  input_file_1 = File.open('file1', 'r')
  input_file_2 = File.open('file2', 'r')

  # Open the file that will be written. Here it is named "output"
  File.open('output', 'w+') do |of|
    # Read the first line from each file
    left = read_line_from_file(input_file_1)
    right = read_line_from_file(input_file_2)

    # Loop until BOTH files have reached their end
    until left.nil? && right.nil?
      # If the first file was successfully read, 
      # attempt to parse the date at the beginning of the line
      left_date = parse_date(left) if left
      # If the second file was successfully read, 
      # attempt to parse the date at the beginning of the line
      right_date = parse_date(right) if right

      # If the first file was successfully read, 
      # but the date was not successfully parsed,
      # the line is a stack trace and needs to be printed
      # because it will be following the related
      # timestamped line.
      if left && left_date.nil?
        of << left

        # Now that we have printed that line, 
        # grab the next one from the same file.
        left = read_line_from_file(input_file_1)
        next

      # If the first file was successfully read, 
      # but the date was not successfully parsed,
      # the line is a stack trace and needs to be printed
      # because it will be following the related
      # timestamped line.
      elsif right && right_date.nil?
        of << right

        # Now that we have printed that line, 
        # grab the next one from the same file.
        right = read_line_from_file(input_file_2)

        # Skip straight to the next iteration of the `until` loop.
        next
      end

      if left.nil?
        of << right

        # Now that we have printed that line, 
        # grab the next one from the same file.
        right = read_line_from_file(input_file_2)

        # Skip straight to the next iteration of the `until` loop.
        next
      end

      # If we got this far, neither of the lines were stack trace
      # lines. If the second file has reached its end, we need
      # to print the line we grabbed from the first file.
      if right.nil?
        of << left

        # Now that we have printed that line, 
        # grab the next one from the same file.
        left = read_line_from_file(input_file_1)

        # Skip straight to the next iteration of the `until` loop.
        next
      end

      # ADDED THIS SECTION
      # If we got this far, the second file has not
      # reached its end. If the first file has reached
      # its end, we need to print the line we grabbed 
      # from the second file.
      if left.nil?
        of << right

        # Now that we have printed that line, 
        # grab the next one from the same file.
        right = read_line_from_file(input_file_2)

        # Skip straight to the next iteration of the `until` loop.
        next
      end

      # If we got this far, neither file has reached its 
      # end and both start with timestamps. If the first file's
      # timestamp is less, it is older.
      if left_date < right_date
        of << left

        # Now that we have printed that line, 
        # grab the next one from the same file.
        left = read_line_from_file(input_file_1)

        # Skip straight to the next iteration of the `until` loop.
        next
      # Either the timestamps were the same or the second one is
      # older.
      else
        of << right

        # Now that we have printed that line, 
        # grab the next one from the same file.
        right = read_line_from_file(input_file_2)

        # Skip straight to the next iteration of the `until` loop.
        next
      end
    end
  end
ensure
  # Make sure that the file descriptors are close.
  input_file_1.close
  input_file_2.close
end
```

Comment: Sorry for the late respons, had some stuff to take care of. So my output only shows it as an output. Not sorted at all.  When you say: if left && left_date.nil? I like the idea with "until left.nil? && right.nil?" because it will force both files to go to the end. But the parse date? What did you do there? I'm doing it like this. if left[my_regex] and it seems alot easier instead of parsing dates. But as it is now I don't get it sorted. But I will try to change some stuff in your code. Thanks alot!

Comment: I went through and commented everything so that you can get a better understanding of what every piece of my code is doing. Also I realized that there was a bug which was probably causing the lines not to be in order correctly. You can see the section I added marked with the `# ADDED THIS SECTION` comment.

Comment: I used your code and changed some to match my preferences, thank you so much! The comments are great!